# cannot unpack non-iterable object / iteraing through array of objects in python

Tags: python

I want to iterate through all objects in an array of URL objects I've got

```
class Url(object):
    pass

a = Url()
a.url = 'http://www.heroku.com'
a.result = 0
b = Url()
b.url = 'http://www.google.com'
b.result = 0
c = Url()
c.url = 'http://www.wordpress.com'
c.result = 0

urls = [a, b, c]

for i, u in urls:
    print(i)
    print(u)
```

However, when I run this script, it comes back with the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Url object
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Url(object):
    pass

a = Url()
a.url = 'http://www.heroku.com'
a.result = 0
b = Url()
b.url = 'http://www.google.com'
b.result = 0
c = Url()
c.url = 'http://www.wordpress.com'
c.result = 0

urls = [a, b, c]

for i in urls:
    print(i)
```

To iterate though the urls. To get the result and urls (which I think you are trying to do), do this:

```
class Url(object):
    pass

a = Url()
a.url = 'http://www.heroku.com'
a.result = 0
b = Url()
b.url = 'http://www.google.com'
b.result = 0
c = Url()
c.url = 'http://www.wordpress.com'
c.result = 0

urls = [a, b, c]

for c,i in enumerate(urls):
    print("index is ",c)
    print(i.result)
    print(i.url)
```

Comment: that works, do you know how I'd get the index as well?

Comment: @JackRobson See [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)